# how can i get audio's duration without getting loaded in js

Tags: javascript, audio, html5-audio, avaudioplayer

let's imagine if i'm building a music player okay ? actually i did it but i faced a problem when i try to get list of the songs and get their duration i must create audio element for each song and it waste alot of data
so there's in a pure js code or another without writing duration statically ?
this is my code

```
    songs.map((song) => {
        if(!song.hasOwnProperty("duration")){
            let aud = new Audio();
            aud.src = `audios/${song.audioName}.mp3`
            aud.addEventListener('loadedmetadata',() => {
                let durationAud = aud.duration;
                song.duration = durationAud;
            })
        }
    })

}
```

Comment: You'll have to read about the `MP3 header structure` to know what you're doing (or try to search in Google for some `JS MP3 header parser` library). Anyways... To get duration you have to check the first 4 bytes because that is the header of one single MP3 **frame** (and do a lot of bit extractions and calculations). Find out the frame's size in bytes length and use that against total file bytes length to calculate how many frames exist. An MPEG audio frame holds X-amount of millisecs of sound (it depends on MP3 type) so you can know duration from knowing how many total frames.

Comment: PS: If you can make a demo code that reads an MP3's first four bytes (binary data) into an `arrayBuffer` then I can help your extract duration from the 4 bytes. You'll need to make an `XMLHttpRequest` or `fetch` call to get the file bytes.

Answer (score 2):

You would solve this creating a row in a database with your audio file's metadata. Then, you would request that data on your frontend with an AJAX call.